# Can't figure out how to get 3x4 grid with Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a simple squared items grid to display images. I have 12 images I need to display, so I thought about 4 rows and 3 cols grid, but with no success. I tried searching and watching tutorials but nothing works for me. I have never tried Bootstrap before.

This is what I tried so far:

```
      <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-md-4"><img src="./Images/food/1.jpg" class="foodImage"></div>
        <div class="col col-md-4"><img src="./Images/food/1.jpg" class="foodImage"></div>
        <div class="col col-md-4"><img src="./Images/food/1.jpg" class="foodImage"></div>

        <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col col-md-4"><img src="./Images/food/1.jpg" class="foodImage"></div>
        <div class="col col-md-4"><img src="./Images/food/1.jpg" class="foodImage"></div>
        <div class="col col-md-4"><img src="./Images/food/1.jpg" class="foodImage"></div>

        <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col col-md-4"><img src="./Images/food/1.jpg" class="foodImage"></div>
        <div class="col col-md-4"><img src="./Images/food/1.jpg" class="foodImage"></div>
        <div class="col col-md-4"><img src="./Images/food/1.jpg" class="foodImage"></div>

        <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col col-md-4"><img src="./Images/food/1.jpg" class="foodImage"></div>
        <div class="col col-md-4"><img src="./Images/food/1.jpg" class="foodImage"></div>
        <div class="col col-md-4"><img src="./Images/food/1.jpg" class="foodImage"></div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: No, it just show one row, and put all the image (and rows) on top of each other. so it looks like I have one row with three images.

Comment: You need `.foodImage{width:100%;}`. Please check here https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/yLLpjXX?editors=1100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exapmle is working fine here:

[Codepen - example](https://codepen.io/barbug/pen/abbEGWK)

Maybe you did not add bootstrap stylesheet in head?

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```